# Test issue in semantic segmentation using DL4J

Tags: image-segmentation, deeplearning4j

I have trained a U-net based model on DL4J on medical images. The code above is for testing the model. my objective is to test the model on 34 2d medical images separately and get the segmentation metrics (accuracy, recall…) for each image, so i tried two ways:
1- when i put all the 34 images in the test folder (“testI”) and i run the code above which will load all the images and test image by image i get good segmentation performance for all the images (even without reset() method),
2- but when i put just one image that i want to test from the 34 in test folder and i execute the code above i get bad results in term of accuracy, recall…), that means i get different segmentation results for the same images by using the two approaches.
This is my label generator code: https://gist.github.com/AbdelmajidB/fccb871836746dd4f0d6e32828eadcdf            The following code is used test the model image by image: https://gist.github.com/AbdelmajidB/92f5fc3013c81b28c898b64118b6adb5

Comment: We would need to see your code for all of the calculations. It's kinda hard to reproduce how you would be doing that. An exact reproduction is needed.

Comment: Hi adam, thank you for your reply. I added more clarification in the text above.